# Intersection of two vector lines

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

So I have this question here:

> Let particle $P_1$ have linear motion given by $l_1(t)=(1,0,1)+t(2,1,1)$ and particle $P_2$ have linear motion given by $l_2(t)=(0,2,1)+t(3,1,-3)$.
>
> $a)$ At what time is the distance between $P_1$ and $P_2$ minimal?
>
> $b)$ What is the minimal distance $d$ between these two particles?
>
> $c)$  Now consider two particles $P_1$ and $P_2$ , each performing a linear motion in $\mathbb{R}^n$ . Let $d$ be the minimal distance between the two particles, and let $D$ be the distance between the traces of the two motions. Analyze the possible relationships between $d$ and $D$. - Recall: The trace of a particle motion is the set of places that the particle visited during its trip.

I already solved part $a)$. The answer is $\frac{1}{17}$.

For part $b)$, I have the time from part b and I know that the distance between $P_1$ and $P_2$ is $\sqrt{(1+2t-3t)^2+(t-2-t)^2+(1+t-1+2t)^2}$ or simply $\sqrt{17t^2-2t+5}.$ So would I just plug in $t=\frac{1}{17}$ into here and call it a day?

As for part $c$, what is it even asking? I have no idea how to even start it...

Comment: Just call it a day.

Comment: For (c) consider whether the traces are parallel or skew or meet at some point.

Comment: They're skew. I know that much.

Comment: @FutureMathperson They may be skew in parts (a) and (b), but (c) is asking about the general case. Also, which of $d<D,d=D,d>D$ do you think are possible?